# Get List Data of selected Column from Table

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to get data of selected columns from a table and return that data in repository class. But my query does not return any data.

My Code is:

```
 public  IQueryable<BusinessProfile> GetBusinessProfileAddress()
    {

        var y = _db.Set<BusinessProfile>().Where(x => x.Deleted == false).Select(x => new
        {
            x.ID,
            x.Address.StreetName,
            x.Address.Number,
            x.Address.Complement,
            x.Address.PostalCode,
            x.Address.Neighborhood,
            x.Address.City,
            x.Address.State
        });
        var d=from a in BusinessProfile select a. 

        return  y; ;
    }
```

Note: Here "return y" is in showing error.

Comment: If your code is showing an error, you should put the error message in your question, to help others understand your problem.

Comment: What is your expected return type for `GetBusinessProfileAddress`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't even build because you haven't finished this query: `var d=from a in BusinessProfile select a.`, but, you are not using the `d` variable at all so you should remove the whole `var d=from a in BusinessProfile select a.` line. And you don't need 2 semicolons after `y`. So, your code should look like this:

```
public IQueryable GetBusinessProfileAddress() {

    var y = _db.Set<BusinessProfile>().Where(x => x.Deleted == false).Select(x => new
    {
        x.ID,
        x.Address.StreetName,
        x.Address.Number,
        x.Address.Complement,
        x.Address.PostalCode,
        x.Address.Neighborhood,
        x.Address.City,
        x.Address.State
    });

    return  y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your current code, you will get error like

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists**

If you want to return the new type, you may consider define a new model and change `BusinessProfile`.

```
public IQueryable<BusinessProfileVM> GetBusinessProfileAddress()
{
    var y = _appDbContext.Set<BusinessProfile>().Where(x => x.Deleted == false).Select(x => new BusinessProfileVM
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        StreetName = x.Address.StreetName,
    });

    return y; 
}
public class BusinessProfileVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

}
```